# Writing scalars into a file in Stata

Tags: file-io, stata, scalar

I want to write scalars that have some pre-generated values into a file. This is a sample of that closely resembles what I am trying to accomplish but those scalars are not writing any output. I tried to to dereference the scalar as can be seen in the code with no success.

```
scalar Sc1b  = 11
scalar Sc2b  = 22
scalar Sc3b  = 33
scalar Sc4b  = 44
scalar Sc5b  = 55
scalar Sc6b  = 66
scalar Sc7b  = 77
scalar Sc8b  = 88

file open myfile using"C:/mytable.txt", write replace

forvalues i=1/8 {
    forvalues q=1/8 {
        display `i', `q', `Sc`i'b', ("`Sc`i'b'"), ("`Sc("`i'")b'")  
        file write myfile ("`i'") _tab ("`q'") _tab `Sc`i'b' _tab ("`Sc`q'b'") _tab ("`Sc("`q'")b'") _n
    }
}

file close myfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to dereference scalars here. They don't have temporary names; you assigned them permanent names, so there are no aliases to peel off. I am guessing that the multiple versions of code for writing the scalar were guesses at the correct code and that you only need each scalar once. I also removed the rather specific Windows reference for the sake of those on other platforms.

```
scalar Sc1b  = 11
scalar Sc2b  = 22
scalar Sc3b  = 33
scalar Sc4b  = 44
scalar Sc5b  = 55
scalar Sc6b  = 66
scalar Sc7b  = 77
scalar Sc8b  = 88

file open myfile using "mytable.txt", write replace

forvalues i=1/8 {
    forvalues q=1/8 {
        display `i', `q', Sc`i'b 
        file write myfile ("`i'") _tab ("`q'") _tab (Sc`i'b) _n
    }
}

file close myfile
```

Note, however, that this code assumes that there are no variables with the same name or whose names abbreviate to the same name as your scalars. Scalars and variables share the same namespace. If necessary, disambiguate using `scalar()`.

Comment: Perfect! This answers my question. Thank you very much!